# Saxon.Api.StaticError: 'xsl:import-schema requires Saxon-EE' with .net API

Tags: xslt, saxon

I've downloaded the .NET Saxon API. I've compiled and run the EE sample application.
Some of it required the license to be present, and I have a license file, which seemed to make it work.

I wanted to use `xsl:import-schema` in my xslt, and this xslt works in the Oxygen editor (which has its own EE license).

If I take the simple xslt example from the saxon sample and then attempt to get it to compile my xslt with the `import-schema` instruction I get:

```
    Saxon.Api.StaticError: 'xsl:import-schema requires Saxon-EE'
```

That is true. However I am already explicitly referencing the Saxon EE library, so that shouldn't be an issue (see below for a clue):

Here's my code:

```
            var samplesDir = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            String dir = samplesDir.LocalPath;
            String sourceFile = Path.Combine(dir,"po.xml");
            String styleFile = Path.Combine(dir,"po.xsl");

            // Create a Processor instance.
            Processor processor = new Processor();

            // Load the source document
            DocumentBuilder builder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();
            builder.BaseUri = new Uri(sourceFile);

            XdmNode input = builder.Build(File.OpenRead(sourceFile));

            XsltCompiler compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
            //compiler.SchemaAware = true;
            compiler.BaseUri = new Uri(styleFile);
            // fails on next line
            Xslt30Transformer transformer = compiler.Compile(File.OpenRead(styleFile)).Load30();

            // Set the root node of the source document to be the global context item
            transformer.GlobalContextItem = input;

            // Create a serializer, with output to the standard output stream
            Serializer serializer = processor.NewSerializer();
            serializer.SetOutputWriter(Console.Out);

            // Transform the source XML and serialize the result document
            transformer.ApplyTemplates(input, serializer);
```

Note that if I comment out the explicit setting to set the `SchemaAware` setting to true, it says:

```
    net.sf.saxon.trans.LicenseException
      HResult=0x80131500
      Message=Requested feature (schema-aware XSLT) requires Saxon-EE. You are using Saxon-EE software, but the Configuration is an instance of net.sf.saxon.Configuration; to use this feature you need to create an instance of com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseConfiguration
      Source=saxon9ee
      StackTrace:
       at net.sf.saxon.Configuration.checkLicensedFeature(Int32 feature, String name, Int32 localLicenseId)
       at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet..ctor(Compilation compilation)
       at net.sf.saxon.style.StylesheetModule.loadStylesheet(Source styleSource, Compilation compilation)
       at net.sf.saxon.style.Compilation.compileSingletonPackage(Configuration config, CompilerInfo compilerInfo, Source source)
       at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(Source source)
       at Saxon.Api.XsltCompiler.Compile(Stream input)
       at ValidateXslt.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\m_r_n\source\repos\SaxonEEExample\ValidateXslt\Program.cs:line 33
```

This is a better clue. It's telling me I **am** using saxon EE, but I need an instance of `com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseConfiguration` somehow.

Why am I getting this error message?

Answer (score 1):

you need to tell the processor to behave like a licensed copy (seems a bit odd)

```
        Processor processor = new Processor(true);
```

Simple, I'd copied an example that didnt need fancy features, but I'll leave this question as it is, just in case someone else has the same issue.

Comment: Yep, I'm afraid this is a common mistake. We ought to take another look to see whether there's a better solution. It's hard to do without breaking compatibility.

Comment: ahha, wait for the next question, driving me mad!